# Beamer: How to uncover content precisely once, in the current slide?

Tags: beamer, overlays

Although not explicit in the `beamer` manual, I figure that `<+>` overlay specification means "the current slide only". I am now in the process of composing a fairly complicated slide show with `beamer` and I am stuck with the exact semantics of `<+>`. Here is my attempt, which seems to work great for ordinary text, but messes up stuff after that:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings,tikz}
\lstset{
        basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily, 
        tabsize=2,                 
        extendedchars=true,       
        breaklines=true,         
        keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue}\textbf,
        commentstyle=\color{ForestGreen},
        stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry}\ttfamily, 
        escapechar=`
 }

 \newcommand\M[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\node[yshift=0.7ex](#1){};}}
 \newcommand\PC[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\node[circle,inner sep=2pt,fill=red!50] at (#1) {};}}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}[fragile]\frametitle{Program}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=pascal]
Program My;
VAR
  one, two: Integer;
Begin `\M{pc1}`
    one := 1; `\M{pc2}`
    two := 2; `\M{pc3}`
    one := one + two; `\M{pc4}`
    two := two + one; `\M{pc5}`
end. `\M{pc6}`
\end{lstlisting}
\uncover<+>{One}%
\uncover<+>{Two}%
\uncover<+>{Three}%
\uncover<+>{Four}%
\begin{uncoverenv}<+->\PC{pc1}\end{uncoverenv}%
\begin{uncoverenv}<+->\PC{pc2}\end{uncoverenv}%
\begin{uncoverenv}<+->\PC{pc3}\end{uncoverenv}%
\begin{uncoverenv}<+>\PC{pc4}\end{uncoverenv}% Note that we use <+> here, not <+->
\begin{uncoverenv}<+->\PC{pc5}\end{uncoverenv}%
\begin{uncoverenv}<+->\PC{pc6}\end{uncoverenv}%
\uncover<+->{After}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here is what I get (see the attached animated gif)

- Texts "one", "two", etc. are shown as expected; one per slide.
- Program counters 1-3 show as expected, from the current slide till the end.
- Program counter 4 shows and disappears (as expected?)
- Program counters 5-6 never show up.

[image]

A similar problem occurs with hard coded numbers, e.g., with the following input:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings,tikz}
\lstset{
      basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily, 
      tabsize=2,                 
      extendedchars=true,       
      breaklines=true,         
      keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue}\textbf,
      commentstyle=\color{ForestGreen},
      stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry}\ttfamily, 
      escapechar=`
}

\newcommand\M[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\node[yshift=0.7ex](#1){};}}
\newcommand\PC[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\node[inner sep=1pt,circle,radius=2pt,fill=red!50] at (#1) {};}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]\frametitle{Program}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=pascal]
Program My;
VAR
  one, two: Integer;
Begin `\M{pc1}`
    one := 1; `\M{pc2}`
    two := 2; `\M{pc3}`
    one := one + two; `\M{pc4}`
    two := two + one; `\M{pc5}`
end. `\M{pc6}`
\end{lstlisting}
\uncover<+>{One}%
\uncover<+>{Two}%
\uncover<+>{Three}%
\uncover<+>{Four}%
\uncover<5-6>{\PC{pc1}}
\uncover<6-6>{\PC{pc2}}
\uncover<7-7>{\PC{pc3}}
\uncover<8-8>{\PC{pc4}}
\uncover<9>{\PC{pc5}}
\uncover<10>{\PC{pc6}}
\uncover<11>{After}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

However, and **this is really strange**, the problem is not there when I use the ordinary `<+->` overlay specification, as explained in the `beamer` manual. That is, if I write

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings,tikz}
\lstset{
      basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily, 
      tabsize=2,                 
      extendedchars=true,       
      breaklines=true,         
      keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue}\textbf,
      commentstyle=\color{ForestGreen},
      stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry}\ttfamily, 
      escapechar=`
}

\newcommand\M[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\node[yshift=0.7ex](#1){};}}
\newcommand\PC[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\node[inner sep=1pt,circle,radius=2pt,fill=red!50] at (#1) {};}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]\frametitle{Program}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=pascal]
Program My;
VAR
  one, two: Integer;
Begin `\M{pc1}`
    one := 1; `\M{pc2}`
    two := 2; `\M{pc3}`
    one := one + two; `\M{pc4}`
    two := two + one; `\M{pc5}`
end. `\M{pc6}`
\end{lstlisting}
\uncover<+>{One}%
\uncover<+>{Two}%
\uncover<+>{Three}%
\uncover<+>{Four}%
\uncover<+->{\PC{pc1}}
\uncover<+->{\PC{pc2}}
\uncover<+->{\PC{pc3}}
\uncover<+->{\PC{pc4}}
\uncover<+->{\PC{pc5}}
\uncover<+->{\PC{pc6}}
\uncover<11>{After}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I obtain: [image]

Comment: I see exactly what I'd expect (`pc5` and `pc6` both appear) provided I give it enough runs for TikZ to get the positions correct.

Comment: Are you sure? I run `pdflatex` like ten times. I edited my question to add the output I get. `pc5` and `pc6` never appear in my output.

Comment: Yes: I've just run TeX Live's update system to be sure there is not a package issue. With an up to date TL and a clean folder, two runs of the example gives the expected output.

Comment: I tried with a clean directory. Nothing better. Are you using tikz 3.0? (I don't). Will have to reinstall texlive for this since the updater is not working with Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: No, just the package versions currently included in TeX Live. Note that if you are getting odd effects with the TikZ stuff this is really nothing to do with `+` notation, as you'd see the same with hard-coded numbers.

Comment: I tried hard coded numbers as you suggest. The problem does not disappear, which may suggest a `tikz` issue, but if I use ordinary `<+->`, it goes a way, which may suggest a beamer related issue.

Comment: Can you add `\listfiles` to your input and make the `.log` available somewhere?

Comment: I purged my entire texlive installation, to install a new version and see if the problem persists. Will post as soon as the new installation is finished.

Comment: Just finished the re-installation of TeX live 2013. Problem seem to have disappeared. Strange...

Comment: OK, in that case I guess close as 'off-topic': likely to be a version issue with a specific package that is no longer reproducible. Or we could just delete ('not useful to future visitors')?

Comment: Not so sure. I spent a full day of work on this bug. I will add an answer to save some time for the next lost soul.

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out `<+>` indeed refers to a single slide, and does not have any side effects. What I witnessed is most probably a bug in one of the packages of TeX live. I installed my version sometime on November 2013. Updating it today, Jan 19th 2014, resolved the problem.